# Simple Probability Formula and Convergence

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the probability of an event A defined as $P(A) = \frac{N_{a}}{N}$.
In order to understand precisely this concept, i hypothesized that the meaning of this formula is :
,

> as i repeat the observation of the event A in practically the same
>   conditions, i get that, as $i$ grows, $\frac{\sum N_{a_{i}}}{\sum N_{i}}\Rightarrow  \frac{N_{a}}{N}$, where $N_{a_{i}}$ is a specific occurrence of event
>   A.

Is it correct ?

Comment: No. It means that if the event $A$ can occur in $N_a$ of a possible $N$ equally likely ways, then the probability is defined to be the ratio. So, if $A$ is the event that a die rolls an even number, then $N_a = |\{ 2,4,6\}|=3$ and $N = | \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}|=6$ so $P(A) = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: I edited my definition

Comment: I edited my comment.

Comment: Extending the probability to more than finite needs more work. In the latter case, one can formalise your statement above in many ways. This is the subject of the many central limit theorems.

Comment: Thanks. Are you implicitely saying that the observations must be done randomly ?

Comment: No. It is a definition. I have not mentioned observations or random. For a finite sample space with equally likely outcomes, the formula above is the definition.

Comment: At some level (and somewhat loosely), probability is about counting. There are powerful tools brought to bear, but at some level it is about counting. Statistics is about modeling & trying to estimate a probability (distribution). This comment is a vast over simplification.

Answer (score 2):

You mention a *limiting process.* My guess is you are looking at the
so-called 'frequentist' formulation of probability.

This formulation of probability requires a repeatable experiment.
Suppose you are tossing a fair coin and are interested in the probability
of getting a Head. For simplicity we denote Heads as $1$'s and Tails as $0$'s 
At the $n$th toss of the coin we get a number $T_i$ which is $0$ of $1.$

After each toss, we look at the number $A_n$
of $1$'s up through the $n$th roll and the ratio $R_n = A_n/n$
which is the proportion of $1$'s up through
the $n$th roll.

If I simulate 4000 tosses of such a coin using a computer, then I might get
a data table with the first 10 rows looking like this:

```
   n t a         r
   1 1 1 1.0000000
   2 1 2 1.0000000
   3 0 2 0.6666667
   4 0 2 0.5000000
   5 0 2 0.4000000
   6 1 3 0.5000000
   7 0 3 0.4285714
   8 0 3 0.3750000
   9 1 4 0.4444444
  10 1 5 0.5000000
```

I happened to get Heads ($1$'s) on tosses 1, 2, 6, 9, and 10.
Up to the 5th roll I had two $1$s for a ratio $R_5 = 0.4$ and
up to the 10th roll I had five $1$s for a ratio $R_{10} = 0.5.$
At the beginning, the ratios $R_n$ fluctuate greatly.

However, if we look at the last ten entries in the data table,
here is what I see:

```
     n t   a         r
  3991 0 2019 0.5058882
  3992 0 2019 0.5057615
  3993 0 2019 0.5056349
  3994 1 2020 0.5057586
  3995 1 2021 0.5058824
  3996 1 2022 0.5060060
  3997 1 2023 0.5061296
  3998 0 2023 0.5060030
  3999 1 2024 0.5061265
  4000 1 2025 0.5062500
```

The values of $R_n$ have stabilized very near to $1/2$, the probability of
getting Heads. A plot of the ratio $R_n$ against $n$ is shown below.

[image]

Because coin tossing is a random process, there is no guarantee what
value $R_{4000}$ will take. A theorem you will likely see a little later
in your course, called the Law of Large Numbers, says $R_n$ tends to
get ever closer to $1/2$ as $n$ increases. Usually, by about $n = 4000$
we get $R_n$ in the range $0.5 \pm 0.016.$

(Somewhere around $n = 300$
we happened to get a lot of Tails, but eventually those 'extra' 
Tails
were balanced by the large patches of results where Heads and Tails
happened to be nearly equal. The blue line will often behave
'badly', with a lot of variability, near the left of the graph where $n$ is small. Certainly, the *coin* is not consciously
keeping track to compensate for patches of strange behavior early on.
It's called the law of *large numbers* because random anomalies early
on get 'swamped out' by huge numbers of tosses later on.)

However, this is not a
deterministic limiting process.  For the sequence $D_n = \frac{n+5}{2n-7}$
we know exactly what $D_n$ will be for each value of $n$ and we can write
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} D_n = 1/2,$ without mentioning anything about
probability.

For the coin-tossing limit, we sometimes write 
$\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} R_n = 1/2$ and say "$R_n$
converges in probability to $1/2.$" But that expression
needs a careful definition before we can prove theorems about it.

Comment: Thanks so much, are you able to explain why, for the toss of a coin, fluctuations show a symmetric behaviour ? See this picture https://ibb.co/dxSqkJ

Comment: In a 30 tosses of a coin the number of heads will be binomial with $n = 30$ and $p=1/2.$ This is a symmetrical random variable centered at the mean $\mu=np = 15$, This binomial random variable has standard deviation $\sigma = \sqrt{15/2}.$ Binomial random variables can be approximated by a normal distribution. The curve in the background is a normal curve with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma.$ // I don't know if you have studies population means and variances, binomial distributions, or normal distributions yet. If yours is a typical probability course all that is coming soon.

Comment: Snooping around a bit I found [_your related Question_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797755/convergence-of-the-law-of-large-number) which has some very nice answers. You are asking good questions.  Wishing you success in your study of probability.